go_jsonnet dependency fails to build with with gazelle and bazel using MODULE.bazel: no repository visible as '@cpp_jsonnet'
I've put together an MVP for a build failure relating to gazelle and com_github_google_go_jsonnet: https://github.com/antholeole/bug-repro/tree/bazel
in short, I have a BUILD.bazel that looks like this:
go_library(
    name = "src_lib",
    srcs = ["main.go"],
    importpath = "repro/src",
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
    deps = ["@com_github_google_go_jsonnet//:go-jsonnet"],
)

building the target (in the repro, //src:src) gives the following output:
no such package '@@[unk
nown repo 'cpp_jsonnet' requested from @@gazelle++go_deps+com_github_google_go_jsonnet]//stdlib': The repository '@@[unknown repo 'cpp_jsonnet' requested from @@gazelle++go_deps+com_
github_google_go_jsonnet]' could not be resolved: No repository visible as '@cpp_jsonnet' from repository '@@gazelle++go_deps+com_github_google_go_jsonnet' and referenced by '@@gazel
le++go_deps+com_github_google_go_jsonnet//astgen:dumpstdlibast'

is there any way to supply the dependency with @cpp_jsonnet? I've tried to add a module that looks like that to the MODULE.bazel (the error changed but did not go away completely), but it smells like an antipattern. Hopefully there's an easier way to get jsonnet with gazelle.
